# Find radius of identical circles within a circular sector

Tags: geometry

[image]

> The diagram shows sector $OCED$ of a circle, with centre $O$ and radius $R$. Two identical circles of radius $r$ are arranged within the sector such that they touch each other. The lines $\overline{OC}$ and $\overline{OD}$ are both tangent to one of the circles at points $A$ and $B$, respectively. Given that $\angle AOB = 60^\circ$ and $R = 10$ cm, show that $r = 2$ cm.

Can I get a hint on this ? I found area of the whole sector , but I got stuck afterwards . Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let the center of the second circle (the one closer to $O$) be $P$. From $\angle AOB=60^\circ$, what is $\overline{OP}$ in terms of $r$?